# How to remove currency in Woo commerce orders list?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using woocommerce plugin but I want to remove currency in orders list how can I do this ?
https://prnt.sc/16x3sl9

Comment: Please, post the code you're trying here. SO is not a coding workforce.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following solutions:

**1. by using the following lines, you will remove all currency symbol:**

```
function rabiei_remove_usd( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
     $currency_symbol = '';
     return $currency_symbol;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'rabiei_remove_usd', 10, 2);
```

**2. by using the following lines, you only remove specific currency symbol. in this case it is `USD`:**

```
function rabiei_remove_usd( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
    switch( $currency ) {
    case 'USD': 
    $currency_symbol = 'USD'; 
    break;
    }
    return $currency_symbol;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'rabiei_remove_usd', 10, 2);
```

add following code to `functions.php` in your Wordpress theme

Comment: I've using multiple currency but I want to only USD currency  will display orders list .
https://prnt.sc/16xcjnf

Comment: Instead of remove can  I set default currency will show orders if possible then where can i find the directory of code of file.

Comment: Try using USD as default currency in WooCommerce in the following URL: `domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings` , replace `domain.com` with your website URL.

Comment: I've using above code its remove currency whole websites

Comment: This is my websites https://hsmart.pk/product/arvi-a/  using currency PKR default but https://prnt.sc/16xe5eg

Comment: As I said in the previous comment go to this URL: hsmart.pk/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings and change default currency to USD or any other currency you prefer. https://ibb.co/x6fxxwJ

Comment: Can You guide me  where can I find all orders list  file directory 
https://prnt.sc/16xg0fc